# Odd NuGet cache issue; does NuGet keep track of package updates made?

Tags: nuget

I happened to get into a bit of a mess yesterday with our NuGet repository, and I've resolved it - but wanted to confirm my suspicions as to why it happened.

I did the following:

1. Amended some files
2. Packed the nuspec which includes these files
3. Pushed to our NuGet repository and confirmed
4. Confirmed that the NuGet repo had the latest version by downloading them on a dev environment
5. The changes I'd made were not included in the update in this dev environment (realised I hadn't updated the correct files). So I packed and pushed again **without incrementing the version**
6. Downloaded the nupkg on a different dev environment, still the changes were not there.
7. Took the exact same NuGet package and placed it in a local dir, and noticed when I updated from there it *did* include the changes.

### Question

You'll notice as part of step 4 the old (incorrect) NuGet package was downloaded onto dev environment 1. Would NuGet have known this and, due to a lack of sound versioning, cached or kept hold of this copy somehow (despite my new push) and only allowed other dev environments this version and not the newest?

NOTE: I cleared the local cache on both dev environments prior to any updates made. My question was whether this was a server-side thing or not.

Comment: I would guess it depends on what server you are using. I do not believe you can push a NuGet package with the same version to nuget.org for example.  Also if you had already updated the NuGet package in your project then updating it again with a newer NuGet package having the same version would not do anything to your project since NuGet would think it had already been updated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the copy of the package that is added to the packages folder in your solution NuGet will also cache packages already used in the following directory: C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.nuget\packages. Therefore if you do not change the version after making change you will have to remove the cached version from the directory I listed above for it to get the new changes since you did not change the package version.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar same problem. It's seem like a old [issue.](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3116)

So I will clear the http cache after I update the package version.

`nuget locals http-cache -clear`

It will work when you update your project package version.